# Minimize class method with class attributes as parameters

Tags: python, class, oop, optimization, calibration

How do I make that a class like this:

```
class Conic:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_value(self) -> float:
        return (self.x - 2) ** 2 + (self.y + 3) ** 2
    
    def calibrate(self):
        pass
```

Calibrates its attributes `x` and `y` such that it minimizes the return value of `get_value()` method. Preferably inside the same class, as in `calibrate()` method.

Expected behaviour:

```
c = Conic(0,0)
print(c.get_value())
--> 13
c.calibrate()
print(c.get_value(), c.x, c.y)
--> 0 2 -3
```

Comment: What do you want to minimise, with respect to what? if x and y and fixed, then `get_value` always returns the same thing. If you want to minimise for x and y, then the minimum value will be 0, for x=2 and y = -3. Is that what you need?

Comment: You can't apply XOR to float values. Please give an example of what you'd expect get_value() to return for specific values of x and y. If you construct an instance of Conic with float values you'll get a runtime TypeError exception

Comment: As stated, I want to minimize `get_value()` calibrating `x` and `y`. I'm adding expected behaviour to the question.

Comment: @OliverMohrBonometti Your type hints suggest that you want to pass float values to the class constructor yet you pass integers. If you pass values of type int then you will get a value of -5 for x==0 and y==2. However, if you pass float values you'll get a TypeError exception. Please explain why you expect a value of 13 for those inputs. Also, calibrate() does nothing

Comment: - It is just a type hint. Python is not strongly typed. Using `int` or `float` will not raise an exception. - 13 is the result of get value with initial value given in `c = Conic(0, 0,)`, therefore `get_value()` will calculate `(0 - 2)^2 + (0 + 3)^2 = 4 + 9 = 13`. - `calibrate` does nothing as that is the function I don't know how to code. And there should be the code that "finds" `x = 2`, `y = -3`.

Comment: @OliverMohrBonometti I am aware that Python is not strongly typed. However, the fact remains that if you pass float values you **will** get an exception due to your attempt at XOR on those values. Try it. Also, (0-2)^2 is **not** equal to 4. It is -4. Furthermore, (0+3)^2 is equal to 1 and **not** 9 as you seem to think

Comment: It seems that `^` does not behave as expecte. Replacing it with `**`.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "calibrate". Do you want to find the values of `x` and `y` that minimize `c.get_value()`, regardless of the original values?

Comment: Yes. "Calibrates its attributes `x` and `y` such that it minimizes the return value of get_value() method"

Comment: Have you looked into SymPy Solevers?  https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the posted case but it is not a good solution by any standard. I am posting it just to give you an idea of a possible approach.

The code is pretty self-explanatory. It generates a bunch of random x y values, then tests them, and finally outputs the ones that have given the best result.

```
class Conic:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_value(self) -> float:
        return (self.x - 2) ** 2 + (self.y + 3) ** 2
    
    def calibrate(self):
        r = None
        base = self.get_value()
        trials = [randint(-10, +10) for n in range(1000)] #modify this in case of more complex equations
        while trials:
            x = trials.pop()
            y = trials.pop()
            self.x, self.y = x, y
            new = self.get_value()
            if new < base:
                base = new
                r = (x, y)
        return r


c = Conic(0,0)
x, y = c.calibrate()
print(x, y) #2 -3
```

Here is an alternative using nested for loops instead of random integers. But still, it work only because we expect the values to be small integers.

```
def calibrate(self):
    r = None
    base = self.get_value()
    for x in range(-10, 10):
        for y in range(-10, 10):
            self.x, self.y = x, y
            new = self.get_value()
            if new < base:
                base = new
                r = (x, y)
    return r
```